# Outlook 2016 does not render logo (image) in Event Email invitation

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, outlook-web-addins

We have an O365 add-in that works on Calendar. It puts HTML to the body of the invite. All works well except the Image we put. How to make the image appear in the Invitation email view?

```
var logo = "<div style=\"line-height:60px\"><img src=\"https://static-a.test.com/a2/custom-assets/enterprise/4714/isg_logo/d05aa76d58614c0e88b864eec963cec0.png\" height=\"30\" alt=\"Test Meet\" style=\"user-select: none;\" tabindex=\"0\"></div>";

var formattedBody = agenda
            + _.repeat(newLine, 1)
            + logo
            + testInvitation;

return Q.oinvoke(Office.context.mailbox.item.body, "setAsync", formattedUserBody, { coercionType: coercionType })
           .then(function() {
                    logger.info("Add meeting completed successfully");
                });
```

Is there another way to fix it or is it a known limitation of Outlook?

- Logo renders properly in Calendar view, not on Email view
- Some VSTO add-in can render the logo, but not Office 365 addin
- Logo is seen in OWA and Mobile apps, but not in Outlook 2016 Mac and windows

We fixed the issue by following this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3128018/tables-images-and-attachments-are-missing-in-the-received-meeting-requ) in Outlook 2013.

----- **01/09/19 - Update on Issues following the Solution provided** ----------

The primary issue reported got fixed by the solution. Now, we can see Logo in email invitation, but it is broken in Calendar view.

[image]

The changed code:

```
var formattedBody = agenda
        + _.repeat(newLine, 1)
        +  "<img src='cid:testMeet.png'/>"
        + testInvitation;


Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync(
  "https://static-a.test.com/a2/custom-assets/enterprise/4714/isg_logo/d05aa76d58614c0e88b864eec963cec0.png",
  "testMeet.png",
  {asyncContext: null, isInline: true},
  function (asyncResult)  {
        Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync( 
    formattedBody,
          { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html, asyncContext:null }); 
   });
```

This fix also breaks the logo rendering in Outlook Mobile App. Please advise as we need to have the logo between Agenda (if any) and our Text.

---- Screenshot 01/16/2019 -----

[image]

------ Outlook Matrix 01/26/2019 -------

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Adding an image to the body this way is incorrect, and as you have seen, sometime buggy. Instead you should use [`addFileAttachmentAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.7/office.context.mailbox.item#addfileattachmentasyncuri-attachmentname-options-callback), more specifically the `isInline` property, which will allow you to use a `cid:` reference to add your image.

An example of this would be:

```js
Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync(
  "https://static-a.test.com/a2/custom-assets/enterprise/4714/isg_logo/d05aa76d58614c0e88b864eec963cec0.png",
  "testMeet.png", 
  {asyncContext: null, isInline: true},  
  function (asyncResult)  {
        Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync( 
          "<img src='cid:testMeet.png'/>", 
          { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html, asyncContext: null });
});
```

Comment: @outlook-add-in-team-msft - The solution worked for email view but broke in Calendar view. The explanation is lengthy so updated the question on 10th Jan 2019.

Comment: The image at: https://static-a.test.com/a2/custom-assets/enterprise/4714/isg_logo/d05aa76d58614c0e88b864eec963cec0.png is returning a http status 302 (error redirect) so the attached file isn't actually an image. I replaced your code with this link to an image: http://i.imgur.com/WJXklif.png and it worked. As a side note, if your http image has no-cache flags in the headers, it also will cause problems with downloading and attaching the image.

Comment: @outlook-add-in-team-msft -  Sorry - that's a dummy link I used here. We used the image link that you have shared above. The behavior is no different than what I mentioned on 01/10. It just works for Email view, not for Calendar view. Can you please advise, how we can make it render in Calendar view?

Comment: We are looking into this bug. I am able to repro when sending from Outlook Desktop Win32 to other clients...but only when sent to e-mail addresses that are outside my organization. For example, if I run your code from joe@contoso.com, sending a meeting to bob@contoso.com, bob receives the Meeting Request (in email) and the Calendar Item with proper pictures. However with joe@contoso.com TO sue@othercompany.com. Sue will receive e-mail meeting requests, and calendar items with the broken image.

Comment: Can you describe in detail your repro steps? As your "Email View" and "Calendar View" are a bit confusing. And I want to make sure your symptoms match the ones I have seen. For the most part I have seen Both the Meeting Request (Email View?), and "Calendar View" either both work, or both don't work, as long as they are the same user. And only when sent to a user from another domain does it break.

Comment: Until this bug can be investigated, a possible workaround is to use a static image link in your body i.e. <IMG SRC = "http://myserver/img.png">, when sending from faulty clients. The other way is that in our repro steps, we've found that using body.prependAsync, or body.setSelectedData doesn't repro the issue so doing something like: https://pastebin.com/qQP6kFNw

Comment: We are using a static image URL. We also used the body.prependAsync and body.setSelectedData. Neither solved the issue in cross-domain image rendering nor in Calendar View. You can refer https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDwbX.png for the Calendar vs Email view comparison.

Comment: In your screenshots it looks like you are using MAC outlook, was the meeting request created and sent through windows/MAC? Also, it seems like you are viewing the emails on a MAC, do you see this broken behavior on windows too when viewing the email?

Comment: Could you share more elaborate repro steps with the exact code you are using to test this. Also, please send along versions of outlook (build number and platform) you are using to compose the message(both email and appointment) in and the version of outlook you are reading the received message in along with which one's work and which one's doesn't. We tested the code snippet you provided with setselectedData/prepend and were able to receive the email properly. This was tested by composing and receiving through windows outlook C2R.

Comment: Are you also saying that if you link directly to the image instead of using addFileAttachment, that the scenario is also broken? (i.e. if you just do body.setAsync() with a text of <IMG SRC = 'http://contoso.com/mylogo.jpg'> also does not work?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Attached is the matrix for you to refer - https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8HXI.png. (N/A is Not Applicable)
MAC Version: 16.22 (190123)
Windows Version: 1808 (Build 10730.20264)
All of the solutions proposed above have the same behavior in cross domain image rendering in Email View of the Invitation. We need it work on cross domain, else what's the point in putting the logo.

Comment: For Outlook Desktop on Windows specifically, we were able to reproduce the cross-domain inline attachment issue using body.setAsync, but not body.prependAsync, when sending calendar invitations. For this issue, please consider one of the workarounds in the Jan 15 comment. For compatibility across clients, using a hosted image link may be the best option (see the Jan 15 and Jan 17 comments).

Comment: We have hosted image for this. If we are going to send the invite to cross-domain, still the hosted URL will be same. Are you suggesting that we need to host in the receiver domain? That's impossible. I can schedule meeting from x@mycompany.com to y@anyothercompany.com. How can this solution be scalable? Let me know if I understood it all wrong.